# Where is the Error ?? Javascript variable to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying since last two hours and struck somewhere in the below code, i have tried several methods. But no success. Can you check where i am doing mistake in the mentioned code ??

```
 <?php $location = echo' ?> document.getElementById("pac-input").value <?php ' ?>
```

and

```
<?php   
    $location = <script>document.getElementById("pac-input").value;</script>"
    echo $location ;
?>
```

I have tried, No idea where i am making mistake. Can anyone check and let me know the error please ? I want to pass the JavaScript variable to PHP Variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't pass a client side variable to php without some sort of communication, such as Ajax fetch etc

Comment: Is it possible to fetch document id through php script. I mean is there any sort of script though which i can access document.getElementById("id1).value through PHP script

Comment: Detect when the value is changed in javascript and send an ajax request to your server with the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second one, you gotdouble quotes to delimit your string and double quotes inside it for pac-input. You have to use simple quote on pac-input.
Missing ; and starting double quotes also.

```
<?php   
$location = "<script>document.getElementById('pac-input').value;</script>";
echo $location; ?>
```

You might need to read some basic tutorial about php syntax because your syntax is somewhat random and show you do not understand what you are doing.

Comment: Ah nevermind, i thought you just want to echo your script. EasyBB is correct you can not pass client side informations (javascript) to the server (php) without a communication between both (ajax or a simple post/get request).

Comment: Thanks, Anyways.. i was just trying to pass the variable to php variable..No issues.. Your code does not work for me.. i will try with AJAX